# Copy changed files, create a changeset and maintain directory structure

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin

I want to copy just the files i've created/edited today into a separate directory "changeset" whilst maintaining their directory structure

I came up with the following script

```
cd ./myproject/

find ./* -mtime -1 -daystart -exec cp {} ../changeset/{} \;
```

The drawbacks of the above is that directories aren't created and the copy throws an error.

I've manually gone into ../changeset/ and create the folder structure until the command runs without errors.. but thats a little tedious.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: cp has a flag to create parents, I think it is -p, but not 100% sure

Comment: @technosaurus There's `mkdir -p` but sadly no `cp` equivalent. `cp -p` and `cp --parents` exist but do other things.

Answer (score 2):

```
find * -mtime -1 -daystart -print0 | cpio -pd0 ../changeset
```

cpio is an old, oddball archival program that is occasionally the best tool for the job. With `-p` it copies files named on stdin to another directory. With `-d` it creates directories as needed.

Comment: I'm on Windows and MingW doesn't seem to have this. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution which isn't as elegant as John's but which isn't reliant on `cpio`, which i dont have.

```
cd ./myproject/

# Create all directories
find ./* -type d -exec mkdir ../changeset/{} \;

# Copy files
find ./* -mtime -1 -daystart -exec cp {} ../changeset/{} \;

# Delete empty directories, run this several times because after moving a child the parent directory needs to be removed
find ../changeset/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```